# React charts with data from mySQL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I want to use charts in my react project, but I have no clue how to implement a chart in react, all the videos I found are out dated.
I'm using React (TS) with function components, nodeJS, mySQL.
How do I create this?
If any one have a guide or can explain to me what to do, I'll be happy.

Comment: I would suggest looking into [Recharts](https://recharts.org/en-US/) or [react-chartjs-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2).

Comment: I tried looking, but I can't understand how to read data from the mySQL database

Comment: Creating charts and reading data from mysql are two different things. The charts would expect data in a certain format, that's what you need to provide. Extraction from data is just node.js task and there are lots of examples how to do it.

Comment: If you have links to guides I would appreciate that.